# How to send the data on external api?

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

I want to send the data on external api and receive on the page. Actually I am new on this for sending the data as a JSON format to the external api.
Here is my code-

```
<input type="hidden" name="hcodes" class="hcodes" value="{!! $datalist->getData !!}">
<div id="response">
</div>

$(".hcodes").each(function(key,str){
Var hcode = $(str).val();
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({hcode});
    //console.log(jsonData);
      $.ajax({
         url: 'some url',           
             type: "POST",      
        Accept: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         api-key: 'providedkey',
        content-type :'application/json',
             dataType: "json", 
             data: jsonData,
             success: function(response){
            alert('success');
             },
             error: function(response){
                alert('error');
             }
        });  

  });
```

Comment: Note that for sending data you need the `POST` type and not the `GET` type

Comment: @ronald -I was already using post method, but not worked